# How do I create a rectangle with an extended corner?

Tags: android, drawable

I want to use rectangle with extended corner as background for View. I need it in `ChatActivity`. Here's picture of it, you can see at the top left corner, what I mean.

[image]

How can I make it happen

Comment: You want to draw a rectangle with a triangle in the corner.

Comment: I get the idea, but can't make it with code

Comment: Simply `extend` a View and `Override` `onDraw()` method. You may prefer extending a `TextView` depending on your requirement.

Comment: You can create a custom view and draw the rectangle yourself in onDraw() or you can use a 9.patch image which is the simpler solution if you don't mind adding additional resources to your app.

Answer (score 0):

in my previous work actually i create that kind of chat bubble using two image, the first is the triangle using a view, and the second one using a view that use a 9-patch drawable

both image is put side by side